# Fragment class not found

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I've just started working on my first Android app and my focus is the main activity of the app, `MathleteIDActivity`, which includes a fragment `TextFragment` which displays some text.

The project builds fine, but crashes as soon as the app is launched. This happens on two different phones running Android `4.x.x`, so fragment support shouldn't be the issue. The stacktrace from `adb logcat` looks like this (package redacted):

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{foo.bar.baz.id.MathleteIDActivity} ...
...
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class fragment
...
Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment .fragments.TextFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: .fragments.TextFragment
...
```

My directory structure seems kosher: I've got the package directories `foo/bar/baz/` inside `src/main/java/` in the project root, and within that package:

```
fragments/
    TextFragment.java
id/
    NFCIDActivity.java
    MathleteIDActivity.java
    ...
...
```

`MathleteIDActivity.java` reads as follows:

```
package foo.bar.baz.id;

import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.Bundle;
import foo.bar.baz.R;

public final class MathleteIDActivity extends NFCIDActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedState) {
        super.onCreate(savedState);
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fragment_text);
        textView.setText("Scan mathlete tag");
    }
}
```

`NFCIDActivity` is an abstract class that extends Android's `Activity`. Its only method is an override of `onCreate`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedState) {
    super.onCreate(savedState);
    setContentView(R.layout.id_activity);
}
```

And `TextFragment.java` reads as follows:

```
package foo.bar.baz.fragments;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import foo.bar.baz.R;

public final class TextFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.text_fragment, container, false);
    }
}
```

In `src/main/res/layout/id_activity.xml` I have the activity layout defined:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <fragment
        android:name=".fragments.TextFragment"
        android:id="@+id/id_message" >
    </fragment>
</LinearLayout>
```

In the same directory, `text_fragment.xml` defines `TextFragment`'s layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I've already tried:

- Adding a public, no-parameter constructor to `TextFragment`. Same errors.
- Referencing the fragment in the layout file by its fully-qualified package name `foo.bar.baz.fragments.TextFragment`. Same errors, now naming the new package.
- Moving `TextFragment`'s source file to the top-level package `foo.bar.baz` and adjusting references. Same errors, now naming the new package.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can we see the code for your MathleteIDActivity.java and TextFragment.java? Also, does your fragment have it's own layout?

Comment: Yep. I've added that info.

Comment: Could you post your `build.gradle`? Have you tried to to instantiate your fragment programatically using `FragmentManager`? If so, do you get same error?

Comment: Take a look at `build.gradle` [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jakobcornell/dubois-traffic-puzzle/17209007a816c644f2b7764df84cda2585dad781/app/build.gradle). I'm not familiar with `FragmentManager`, but I'll look into it and post updates.

Comment: @KarsenGauss Interestingly, creating and adding the fragment programmatically works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instantiate your fragment programatically using `FragmentManager` as a quick solution:

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

TextFragment tf = new TextFragment();
ft.replace(R.id.container, tf);
ft.commit();
```

As for your approach, use a canonical package name instead and clean-build your project. Then pay attention to the error message (it can't be "same error" since it should at least mention different package name).

Comment: The package cited in the error messages did indeed change. Fully-qualified package name plus clean build fixed the problem.

Comment: This is the Java solution, sure, but what about the XML method of using the Fragment?

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was using a navigation graph and when navigating to my settings fragment, it crashed with the error-  *Fragment Class not set*. I had to go to the nav graph code and entered the android: name property for the Fragment class i.e com.example.company.features.Settings